# Where is the RAM consumption?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm having a problem of RAM consumption with Python 2.7. When I load a pickled object the memory usage of the python process is far more than the object size on RAM. 
Here is the code:

```
import dill
import time
import psutil
from pympler import asizeof

with open('results/dynamic_cache_lru_0.250gb.pickle', 'rb') as fh:
    cache = dill.load(fh)
    print('memory used by cache: %.4fmb' % (asizeof.asizeof(cache) / 1024.0 / 1024))
    mi = psutil.Process().memory_info()
    print('rss: %.4fmb' % (mi[0] / 1024.0 / 1024))
    print('vss: %.4fmb' % (mi[1] / 1024.0 / 1024))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
memory used by cache: 247.1717mb
rss: 905.2266mb
vss: 949.2617mb
```

I don't know what is using that extra RAM or if it's being used by the object  itself, why it isn't counted as its size.

Answer (score 0):

I see similar although less extreme results running your code on a pickle of a list of about 275000 dictionaries:

```
before rss: 14.3086mb
before vss: 83.2773mb
memory used by cache: 467.1687mb
after rss: 745.0195mb
after vss: 823.6133mb
```

I don't have an explanation for this, but I can tell you that just calling asizeof.asizeof(cache) increases memory usage for me by over 80 megabytes:

```
before rss: 14.3125mb
before vss: 83.2773mb
before asizeof rss: 663.1797mb
before asizeof vss: 741.8008mb
memory used by cache: 467.1687mb
after asizeof rss: 745.0195mb
after asizeof vss: 823.6055mb
```

Perhaps if you do the same check it will help you narrow down the cause.